# Google Sheet get value from a REST API

Tags: google-sheets

I need to include in a cell on a Google sheet the value of the `ticker.last` attribute in a JSON which is being constantly updated from a REST API located at `https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/ticker/`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following formula:

```
=SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/ticker/"), 1, 4), ":")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since mercadobitcoin returns a JSON, you could use this [ImportJSON Script](https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164).

Then you would call it with

`=ImportJSON("https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/ticker","/ticker/last","noTruncate")`